# Azure DevOps release pipelines "Conflict of operation error " while running one job on microsoft-hosted agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to implement an Azure DevOps Release pipeline to Deploy a machine learning model on Azure ML. I'm using 6 tasks:

- Use python version
- Azure CLI : `az extension add -n azure-cli-ml`
- Azure CLI : `az ml model deploy -g <RG> -w <WS> -n <SN> -f ../metadata/model.json --dc aciDeploymentConfig.yml --ic inferenceConfig.yml --overwrite`
- Bash Task : pip install requirments.
- Azure CLI : Run some integration tests.
- Publish Test Results.

My pipeline fails on the deployment task, with the error: 
`Conflict of operation, another operation on same entity is already running in workspace mlops-wrksp.`
`Script failed with exit code: 1`

No other pipeline is running, I'm using the Microsoft-hosted agent.

Comment: Is this a classic release, or YAML? If YAML, can you include it in your question? can you try adding `az extension list` to your pipeline before the `az extension add`, and include that output in your question? can you include more complete output from your release pipeline run so that we can see context?

Comment: Do you have this error every time? Are there any error messages in the activity log of the workspace?

Comment: Try to see logs in azure ml workspace endpoints, there is deployment log of the model